# Sorting out my Floated divs with percentage widths

Tags: html, css

I have this simple css layout at the heart of my problem:

[image]

The leftside is set to `float:left` and a width of `70%`, the right is set to `float:right` and a width of `30%`.
However this leaves me with a gap where they don't quite touch like i need them too:

[image]

To solve that i can change the percentages to `70.1% and 30%.` which means most of the time the gap is gone but occasionally the rightside gets pushed down below the leftside which is no good!

I tried setting the width of the rightside to `auto` and it pushed the rightside down again but looked like this:

[image]

Then i tried getting rid of the the `float:right` on the rightside. Which ALMOST works except the register_container dropped all the way down to the bottom even though the rest of the divs (also inside of the rightside but listed after the register_container) sat on the right as they should:
[image]

Here's [a paste of my css](http://pastebin.com/m5hK1F9Q), and here's the site I have temporarily uploaded: http://greenevent.site50.net/index.php

If someone could help me solve my problem that would be great! (in case it's not clear, i want the arrangement to look like the first website image posted but without the thin gap.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch your `float: right;` to `float: left;` on your right container. You need to assign a width to the container as well.

There is a bug in webkit browsers that means you don't get 100% at times which can be a bit of a pain.

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/Lyphr/2/

If you change the width on your right container to 27% in Chrome's dev tools you get the layout you're after.

Comment: Oh Thank you! but I think there must be something wrong with my central container because when i changed it as you suggested everything fell to the left: http://i.imgur.com/vCksL.jpg

Comment: Sorry, you have to assign a width to it as well. That solves it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try to float only the left side and have a margin on the right side:

```
​#left
{
   float: left;
   width: 70%;
   background: yellow;
}

#right 
{
   margin-left: 70%;
   background: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2z6KZ/